# Java Webservice returns AnyTypeArrayArray

Tags: java, web-services

I am developing a webservice with java. The service has the following method which returns Object[][]

```
public Object[][] getCars(String manufactor, String market, String year, boolean order, boolean asc, String column){ ... }
```

I can access the webservice without any problems, but the result when calling  the method from the service is

```
AnyTypeArrayArray
```

How can I convert this to the Object[][] I need?

Here is how I am calling the method:

```
    WebserviceService service = new WebserviceService();
    TheWebService dbServer = service.getFASDBWebservicePort();
    AnyTypeArrayArray result = dbServer.getCars(manufactor, market, year, order, asc, columnToOrderBy);
```

Here is what is written in the WSDL:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<!--
 Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01. 
-->
<!--
 Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01. 
-->
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://fasdb.iff/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://fasdb.iff/" name="WebserviceService">
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://jaxb.dev.java.net/array" schemaLocation="http://192.168.1.104:8080/fasdbserver?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://fasdb.iff/" schemaLocation="http://192.168.1.104:8080/fasdbserver?xsd=2"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="queryDatabase">
<part name="arg0" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="queryDatabaseResponse">
<part name="return" type="tns:dbResult"/>
</message>
<message name="getCars">
<part name="arg0" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="arg1" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="arg2" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="arg3" type="xsd:boolean"/>
<part name="arg4" type="xsd:boolean"/>
<part name="arg5" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="getCarsResponse">
<part xmlns:ns1="http://jaxb.dev.java.net/array" name="return" type="ns1:anyTypeArrayArray"/>
</message>
<portType name="FASDBWebservice">
<operation name="queryDatabase">
<input wsam:Action="http://fasdb.iff/FASDBWebservice/queryDatabaseRequest" message="tns:queryDatabase"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://fasdb.iff/FASDBWebservice/queryDatabaseResponse" message="tns:queryDatabaseResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="getCars" parameterOrder="arg0 arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5">
<input wsam:Action="http://fasdb.iff/FASDBWebservice/getCarsRequest" message="tns:getCars"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://fasdb.iff/FASDBWebservice/getCarsResponse" message="tns:getCarsResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="FASDBWebservicePortBinding" type="tns:FASDBWebservice">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc"/>
<operation name="queryDatabase">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://fasdb.iff/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://fasdb.iff/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="getCars">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://fasdb.iff/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://fasdb.iff/"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="WebserviceService">
<port name="FASDBWebservicePort" binding="tns:FASDBWebservicePortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://192.168.1.104:8080/fasdbserver"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

Comment: You're not doing yourself any favours trying to return the result as Object[][]. Why not List<Car> or Car[]?

Comment: I want to display the results in a JTable and the DefaultTableModel takes Object[][] for the values and Object[] for the Captions for the columns. Therefore I thought that return value of Object[] would fit my needs.

Comment: But also with return Type String[] the client get an StringArray